# OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError: hostname "smtp.gmail.com" does not match the server certificate

Tags: centos, smtp, openssl, ruby-on-rails, gmail

This is what i have setup in setup_email.rb file,

```
if Rails.env.production?
  ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
      :address              => "smtp.gmail.com",
      :port                 => "587",
      :domain               => "gmail.com",
      :user_name            => "username",
      :password             => "mypass",
      :authentication       => "login",
      :enable_starttls_auto => true
  }
end
```

**This code works in development and staging envoirnment**.

***This code was working fine on production***, suddenly after several days it stopped working and i  am getting error message.
I have tried setting up `openssl_verify_mode: none` still does'nt work.

> Then i changed gmail account but getting same error. Seems like some
>   server side error

Error:

> OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError: hostname "smtp.gmail.com" does not match the
>   server certificate

I have tried different methods out there on internet but its not working. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `openssl_verify_mode: none` is something you can use in a testing environment, but not in production. There is a reason why you get the error message. Does smtp.gmail.com resolve to the correct IP addresses on your production server? If yes, download the certificate and inspect it.

Comment: How to check "smtp.gmail.com resolve to the correct IP addresses on your production server"?

Comment: This may happen if Gmail has been blocked in your country.

Comment: @ZiaQamar Have you found a solution for this problem please ?

Answer (score 1):

On the same production system use:

```
openssl s_client -connect smtp.gmail.com:587 -starttls smtp -showcerts
```

On my system the output includes:

```
subject=/C=US/ST=California/L=Mountain View/O=Google Inc/CN=smtp.gmail.com
```

Your smtp software probably checks that CN=smtp.gmail.com and it sees something else there. For example, someone could have inserted themselves in the middle between you and gmail.com. Not necessarily in hostile manner, could be a simple `/etc/hosts` modification, or a change on a socks proxy.